# Unable to create point to site connectivity in windows 8.1

Tags: azure, vpn

I have tried to create VPN connection in my windows 8.1 machine.

I have followed the steps mentioned in the setup. While connecting Its shows the error message as:

> "A certificate could not be found that can be used with this
>   Extensible Authentication Protocol. (Error 798)".

How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This typically means that the client certificate is not installed on the Windows machine you are trying to connect from.

On the client machine, please open "certmgr" from command prompt and verify that the client certificate (created/signed by the root certificate) is installed on the machine.

A couple more things to check or verify:

- The P2S root cert, the one you uploaded to Azure, must be in the
  machine's trusted root store in certmgr
- Delete the re-install/import the client cert again, please ensure you
  do NOT check the "Enable strong private key protection. ..."
- (It's a long shot but ...) Check if the following regkey is set to 1:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\PPP\EAP\13
  \SelectSelfSignedCert

If it still fails, collect tracing for further debugging from an elevated command prompt:

- "netsh ras diag se tr en"
- repro the issue (failed connect)
- "netsh ras diag se tr dis"
- Share/send the contents of your Windows\tracing folder

[Edit]
Just found another link with very extensive instructions to try:

https://www.tectimes.net/how-to-microsoft-azure-como-solucionar-el-error-798-a-certificate-could-not-be-used-with-this-extensible-authentication-protocol-en-windows-8-1-en-una-vpn-hacia-azure/

(In Spansh, you will need to translate the page.)

Thanks,

Yushun [MSFT]